# Remove data from array if column is empty on string

Tags: java, csv

I need to remove a line from string if some column is empty:
Check it:

```
ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
        students.add("8246, ,JUCIELLY,SOUSA,ENSINO REGULAR - MEDIO - 1ช SERIE,JUCIELLY.SOUSA@aluno.ma.gov.br,10071999");
        students.add("8246,1282,JUCIELLY,SOUSA,ENSINO REGULAR - MEDIO - 1ช SERIE,JUCIELLY.SOUSA@aluno.ma.gov.br,10071999");
        students.add("8246,1282,JUCIELLY,SOUSA,ENSINO REGULAR - MEDIO - 1ช SERIE,JUCIELLY.SOUSA@aluno.ma.gov.br,10071999");
        students.add("8246,,JUCIELLY,SOUSA,ENSINO REGULAR - MEDIO - 1ช SERIE,JUCIELLY.SOUSA@aluno.ma.gov.br,10071999");
        students.add("8246,1282,,JUCIELLY.SOUSA@aluno.ma.gov.br,10071999");
        students.add("8246,1282, ,,10071999");
```

As you can see some colunms on this strins is EMPTY or " "(have blankspaces)

someone can help me? i think it is easy to do but i tried and failed.

i need a full 7 columns with something. cannot be ,, or blankspaces =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for empty values and keep track of the indices. later remove elements from those indices

```
ArrayList<Integer> badIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i=0; i<students.size ; i++) 
{
    if (students.get(i).matches(".*,\\s?,.*")) {
        badIndices.add(i);
    }
}

for (int b : badIndices)
{
    student.remove(b);
}
```

now, all of the bad entries would have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Split the `String` and see if any indexes are empty or equal to `" "`...

```
String.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are parsing a string in `Java` you can use the `String.split(identifier)` function, which will split a `String` on the character you give the function, and return an `Array` of all things in between the character you are splitting on. What you are trying to do is parse a csv (comma *separated* value) record. So as the naming would suggest, use a "," as your separator.

The below example will split the `String` (a student record) based on the comma value, and then loop through each of the values that are between the commas. It will then call `String.trim()`, which will remove any leading/trailing whitespace from the `String` value, and then check if `String.isEmpty()` returns `true`. If it does, we know that this is an object that should be removed from the list.

```
        String student = "8246, ,JUCIELLY,SOUSA,ENSINO REGULAR - MEDIO - 1ช SERIE,JUCIELLY.SOUSA@aluno.ma.gov.br,10071999";
        String [] studentStringSplit = student.split(",");
        for(String fieldValue : studentStringSplit){
            if(fieldValue.trim().isEmpty()){
                //remove record from list
            }
        }
```

It is worth noted that `Java` is an *Object-Oriented* programming language, so instead of passing 1 large `String` into a `List`, you should instead create a new `Class` to represent these person records with, and then create/use a `List` of each person. But, that would not necessarily change the procedure for finding empty values at all. Just side advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `contains` method of String class:

```
if(element.contains(",,")||element.contains(", ,")){
     //do something
}
```